# rails,devise, heroku and multiple dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku, devise

We have an application running on Heroku, that has multiple dynos. Let's say the application has 2 dynos, and when the user logs in, he's being served by the first dyno. If for some reason, subsequent requests are served by the second dyno, he appears as not being logged in.

The only way to fix this ( from what we tested ) seems to be setting the session store to cookie store. Has anyone else encountered this problem before?

Comment: what is your session store set to otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably didn't have your other session store configured properly.

Did you have the cache service wired in like memcached or redis, so each dyno would look to a shared location for finding session info?

[Heroku memcache from Ruby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache#using_memcache_from_ruby)