# Protect from forgery with exception except: sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706336/get-request-no-json-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-with-devise-3-2-4-on) on CSRF errors.

Is it correct/will it work if I use:

`protect_from_forgery with: exception, except: sign_in`

Or can I only have one or the other?

It works when I run it in development but just not sure it is working as intended.

Comment: are you still unable to push to `heroku`?

Comment: try `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in application controller

Comment: No that issue fixed itself. I am now able to push to heroku

Comment: ok I'll give the null sessions a try. I did read this but thought it was only relevant for json ajax api application requests.

Comment: you may be right. this is what is says inside the application controller: `# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.`  why do you want to use `protect_from_forgery with: exception, except: sign_in`? are you getting any errors?

Comment: just pushed to heroku with the null_session. Instead of erroring now it just constantly redirects to login. Once logged in, I can navigate a couple of times until my authentication token gets destroyed, and I am redirected back to the login screen. Something is destroying my authentication token... so confused. This does not happen in my development environment on my laptop where I am continually navigating around even as we speak.

Comment: When I scale down to 1 dyno the issue is being resolved. I have done some googling and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999853/rails-devise-heroku-and-multiple-dynos. Is this a memcache or redis thing? I have not yet learnt this area.